# Create debian ISO with custom kernels and packages

Tags: linux, debian, iso-image, kernel

I'm trying to create a custom Debian ISO with software that I have built and packaged to .deb. I have my system running on a virtual machine and have fully tested my packages. For the software to work I have customised the kernel to my needs, recompiled and installed.

Now I'm wondering how do I package this into an ISO with the custom kernels and my own packages. I've tried using simple-cdd and a few other methods with no success.

The must be a simple way to build an ISO from you current system setup?

Any advice on how to do this?

Comment: I hope you are right.   What are your intentions with the ISO?   Does your VM system provide a kind of export?

Comment: I intend to distribute the ISO to be downloaded and installed onto a device or VM. I'm using XenServer as the host for my VM, I haven't looked to much into that functionality of Xen.

Comment: Would you want your users to install it or run it immediately (some kind of "live cd" ).

Comment: Definitely install it

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called preseeding. [Here is the official Debian documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed) on the subject for reference.

I have used [this project](https://github.com/netson/ubuntu-unattended) before which is for Ubuntu, but I guess it could easily be tweaked to work with Debian. It creates and unattended installation disk, but if you want your users to answer some of the questions that should be possible by changing the seed file.

Preseeding allows you to add your own packages to ISO's and run any script commands by using the `late_command` option, ie.

`d-i preseed/late_command                                    string      cp -a /cdrom/pool/extras/packages/custom_script.sh /target/usr/local/bin/; in-target /usr/local/bin/custom_script.sh`

[Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/mkjaer/cd4a1fa72fa3224a4651982b86b5d487) with my local script (based on the link above). Line 76 in the bash script is where files are copied into the iso and the last line of the seed file is where it's copied into the final system and potentially executed.

Comment: What have you done here? Have you mounted an ISO, then editing the pool to added the current packages installed under /usr/local/bin?

Comment: The script in link 2 and 3 will download ISO files, mount them, do some changes and then write a new ISO file. The `late_command` option I added was just to show that it's also possible to run a script after end installation.

Comment: Thanks, I'm taking a look at your script and I will give it a try manually.

Comment: Great and just ask question so I can update along the way. It's not a very complicated process but it requires some trial and error.

Comment: You are using mkisofs, mkpasswd and isohybrid in your script which is not available to my OS (Debian Jessie 8.5) it seems. Also how does this line know what packages there are? `if [[ -d "packages" ]]; then`

Comment: On Ubuntu those tools are part of: genisoimage, whois and syslinux-utils in the same order as you put. That line check for a directory called `packages` and if it's there creates a subdirectory on the iso where it copies the files and folders from `packages`

Answer (score -1):

Recreating bootable ISO on Linux is tough. If you have a Windows PC, this can be done easily with the free app ImgBurn. I have done it multiples for creating custom ISO for my VPS.

A few more good tools for this:

[How to edit bootable ISO for free?](https://superuser.com/questions/333870/how-to-edit-bootable-iso-for-free/733492)

[How I do to modify the contents of a ISO file?](https://superuser.com/questions/102384/how-i-do-to-modify-the-contents-of-a-iso-file)